# How to change the css of a standard SF component in LWR site

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lwc-dom, lwr

I have been using an LWR site with no theme selected (Basically a blank theme).
I have used the web-to-lead markup in a custom LWC, but I need to change the styling of the form.
Is there a way to do this at all? I have tried to do a .css file in the component bundle, but that does not work due to the way that LWR changes the classes and id's.
I cannot use styling hooks either, and try and customize those - this again doesn't take affect.
While I know how to change the components styling in a normal component within a Salesforce App with my own LWC's, for some reason the LWR site is not accepting the same methods.
Would a global css file be needed?

I have also tried using JS to create an inline style tag - not best practice, I know. But this also doesn't work.

```
  renderedCallback() {
    const style = document.createElement("style");
    style.innterText = `c-susf-web-to-lead .slds-input{
      background: red;
      color: black;
    }`;
    this.template.querySelector("lightning-input").appendChild(style);
  }
```

Comment: you can use SLDS styles in LWR Sites as well

Comment: Would you mind explaining how? 
Placing something like .slds-button and styling it accordingly in a bundled css file does not work.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this @DarrylLeRoux ? Thanks

Comment: Hey @Swetha, my apologies. Yes, I used a global stylesheet to override the styles. It just really needs to be specific in terms of specificity.

Answer (score 1):

I used a global stylesheet to override the styles. It just really needs to be specific in terms of specificity.